# {"errorCode":"invalid_grant","message":"Login error code:[invalid_grant] description:[user hasn't approved this consumer]"}

Tags: authentication, jwt, apache-camel, salesforce

I'm working on an Apache camel project and trying to authenticate with Salesforce using JWT Bearer and getting the above exception.

I assume this is something that needs to be changed in the salesforce side. Appreciate your help on resolving this.

Please find the full stack trace below,

````
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: salesforce://upsertSObject?rawPayload=true&sObjectIdName=Lead due to: Cannot auto create component: salesforce
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:752) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.resolveMandatoryEndpoint(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:497) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at au.com.test.esb.test.processor.sf.LeadSalesforceRouteBuilder$1.process(LeadSalesforceRouteBuilder.java:109) ~[!/:?]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProcessor.process(DirectVmProcessor.java:57) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmBlockingProducer.process(DirectVmBlockingProducer.java:55) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113) [!/:2.25.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1167) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1159) [!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1056) [!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Cannot auto create component: salesforce
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:483) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:444) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:695) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: {errors:[{"errorCode":"invalid_grant","message":"Login error code:[invalid_grant] description:[user hasn't approved this consumer]"}],statusCode:400}
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.SalesforceSession.parseLoginResponse(SalesforceSession.java:284) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.SalesforceSession.login(SalesforceSession.java:130) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.SalesforceSession.start(SalesforceSession.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.SalesforceComponent.doStart(SalesforceComponent.java:370) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3710) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:477) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getComponent(DefaultCamelContext.java:444) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:695) ~[!/:2.25.3]
    ... 30 more```

Cheers!
````

Comment: Possible solution ? https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Salesforce-CRM-Analytics-Connector-OAuth-JWT-connection-fails-with-user-hasn-t-approved-this-consumer